# How to recover from errors in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

I'm trying to understand how to consume observable sequences and how to recover from errors.

My example is a bit contrived but my real implementation is a bit too complex to show here. Anyway, I have `someObservable` that emits values when the user clicks in the UI. This should trigger a request to the API (GET/POST/etc). The problem is that if the API returns an error, `postData` isn't called anymore after that.

I've make an example here that shows the problem. I've found that I can use `Rx.Observable.of` instead of `Rx.Observable.throw` to keep things running. But that will emit a value to the `subscribe` function. And in my real application `postData` is a service that is reused by multiple parts of the application and I'm not sure that I want to use `of` instead of `throw` there.

So my question is, how do you normally handle things like these?

```
let someObservable = Rx.Observable.timer(1, 1000);

someObservable
.switchMap(data =>  {
  return postData(data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log("POST failed");
})
.subscribe(val => console.log("Success: " + val));

function postData(data) {
  console.log("Will post " + data);

  if (data !== 2) {
    return Rx.Observable.of(true);
  }
  else {
    return Rx.Observable.throw(new Error("400 Bad Request or something"));
  }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/naroyeyive/3/edit?js,console

Comment: Catch immediately: `return postData(data).catch(...)` Modified bin: http://jsbin.com/rujakoguro/3/edit?js,console

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Ok, that seems to work! Do you think you could write an answer and explain briefly _why_ I need to catch there and not like I do in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to send the request again, you may want to look into `retry` and `retryWhen` instead of `catch`.

`catch` will use the returned `Observable` as new "source". [See this bin for an example.](http://jsbin.com/newetid/1/edit?js,console)

`retry(When)` will "re-subscribe" whenever an error occurs, based on the configuration you pass to the operators. You can find examples and more information here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html

Comment: Catch won't terminate the stream if it returns observable that subsequently yields values. It's definitely a recovery point

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was referring to they way Joel was using `.catch()`. Updating my answer to clarify.