# Auth service Angular 2 with Rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, subject

I have a login form component which has the following:

**login.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authenticationService.loginAttempt
        .subscribe(() => this.onSuccess(), err => this.onError(err));
}

login(credentials) {
    this.authenticationService.attempt(credentials);
}
```

My authentication service currently looks like this:

**authentication.service.ts**

```
class AuthenticationService {
    loginAttempt = new Observable<>();
    credentials = new Subject<Credentials>();

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        this.loginAttempt = this.credentials
            .flatMap(credentials => this.makeLoginRequest(credentials);
    }

    attempt(credentials: Credentials) {
        this.credentials.next(credentials);
    }

    private makeLoginRequest(credentials) {
        return this.userService.getTokens(credentials.email, credentials.password);
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that if the login attempt fails, I am able to trigger the `onError` function on the `login.component` to display an error message, but then subsequent login attempts do not trigger the login request anymore, because the `loginAttempt` had an error.

How can I catch the error in the `login.component` so that I can display the error, while still allowing for subsequent retries?

**Edit:**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642966) suggests to use `retry` or `retryWhen`, but I am not sure how to incorporate that based on when the user clicks the login button again. How can I do that (if that is the right approach)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover from errors in rxjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642966/how-to-recover-from-errors-in-rxjs)

Answer (score 2):

What you do is you load it on ngOnit so you load it when the page load.

After that you never reload it again. So the succes stay a succes and the error stay a error.

Put the service call behind the button call and you done.

**Edit**

Change:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.authenticationService.loginAttempt
    .subscribe(() => this.onSuccess(), err => this.onError(err));
}
```

Into:

```
buttonClicked() {
  this.authenticationService.loginAttempt
    .subscribe(() => 
      this.onSuccess(), 
      err => this.onError(err)
      );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate, or better yet write some example code of what you are talking about please?

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean. The problem with this approach seems to me that I could never `subscribe` to the login from anywhere else in my application.

Comment: `subscribeAgain(){ this.buttonClicked() }` Hack it's even public so all components should be able to acces it.